# Get all collection data from mongodb without define bean in springboot JPA

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa, collections

Beacause fields inside mongo collection is changes over object to object. in object there is 4 fields in other there is 8 fields so how we get all the collection data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MongoDB Spring Data's [MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) API methods as shown below.

`The MongoTemplate` class's `findAll` method can be used. The method requires that entityClass be specified. If you don't have an entity class defined, a generic [org.bson.Document](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/org/bson/Document.html) class can be specified (see example code below).

```
public <T> List<T> `findAll`(Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName)
```

> Query for a list of objects of type T from the
>   specified collection.
>
> The object is converted from the MongoDB native
>   representation using an instance of MongoConverter. Unless configured
>   otherwise, an instance of MappingMongoConverter will be used. If your
>   collection does not contain a homogeneous collection of types, this
>   operation will not be an efficient way to map objects since the test
>   for class type is done in the client and not on the server.

Example:

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "test");
List<Document> list = mongoOps.findAll(Document.class, "person");
list.forEach(doc -> System.out.println(doc.toJson()));
```

In the above code, `person` collection is read; and the collection has documents with different fields. For input documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "fld" : "str-1" }
{ "_id" : 3, "fld" : "str-3", "fld2" : 13 }
{ "_id" : 10, "dt" : ISODate("2020-03-07T03:08:49.855Z") }
```

The output is:

```
{"_id": 1.0, "fld": "str-1"}
{"_id": 3.0, "fld": "str-3", "fld2": 13.0}
{"_id": 10.0, "dt": {"$date": 1583550529855}}
```

Comment: and how we add condition on particular fields, and count of fields.

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by "how we add condition on particular fields, and count of fields?". Please update the post with details.

Comment: { "_id" : 1, "fld" : "str-1", "fld2" : 13, "fld4" : 20 }
{ "_id" : 3, "fld" : "str-3", "fld2" : 13, "fld3" : 40 }
{ "_id" : 10, "dt" : ISODate("2020-03-07T03:08:49.855Z") , "fld4" : 20 }

For this data i want count for fld2,fld3 and fld4, and my result is like this : 
{
   fld2 : 2,
   fld3 : 1,
   fld4 : 4
}

Answer (score 1):

you can get the documents like this without jpa repository

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.match;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.newAggregation;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.project;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/url")
    public List<JSONObject> getList() {

    ProjectionOperation project = project().andExclude("_id");


    Aggregation aggregate = newAggregation(project);
    AggregationResults<JSONObject> aggregationResult = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregate,"youCollectionName", JSONObject.class);
    List<JSONObject> result = aggregationResult.getMappedResults();

      return result;

        }
```

Comment: the project I am using just to avoid _id in JSON which MongoDB gives me every time. put these imports if you don't have a library then get from the maven repository from google. I modified the class and I added some imports copy again the code.